# random array that randomize only after reload, javascript only

Tags: javascript

I have created an string array, that hold 6 classes.
The function is called by a button, and for every click a new class i created.
the thing is that when i click the button, i get a randomize class, but if i press the button again. the same class is being displayed and not a random one. If i reload the page, an random class is generated, but as i said, the same class generates when i click again.

This is my random array.

```
   var Array=["dice dice-side-one",
    "dice dice-side-two",
    "dice dice-side-three",
    "dice dice-side-four",
    "dice dice-side-five",
    "dice dice-side-six",
    "dice dice-side-six"];
    var rand = Array[Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length)];

    function addDiceEvent() {
        dicesides_func(rand);

    }
}
```

I paste the full function if the problem is there somewhere.

```
 function AddEvent(){
        var AddEvent = "add";
        var addClassArr= document.getElementsByClassName(AddEvent);
        for(var i=0; i<addClassArr.length; i++){
            var addClass = addClassArr[i];
            addClass.addEventListener("click", addDiceEvent, true);
        }
        var Array=["dice dice-side-one",
        "dice dice-side-two",
        "dice dice-side-three",
        "dice dice-side-four",
        "dice dice-side-five",
        "dice dice-side-six",
        "dice dice-side-six"];
        var rand = Array[Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length)];

        function addDiceEvent() {
            dicesides_func(rand);

        }
    }
    AddEvent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the random thing every time the function is called, not outside of it:

```
function addDiceEvent() {
    var rand = Array[Math.floor(Math.random() * Array.length)];
    dicesides_func(rand);
}
```